# Как сделать border-bottom на всю ширину, но контент на max-width: 1200px?

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать чтобы **border-bottom** был на всю ширину экрана, а контент был только в заданной ширине.

На картинке изобразил наглядно (желтые линии это border-bottom, красные - ширина блока с контентом)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #ffffff;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.case {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1200px;
}

header {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 height: 50px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="case">
  <header>
   <div class="logo">
    Logo
   </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поместите секции в контейнер, у секции ширина сколько вам нужно, у контейнера 100%

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;

}

.container {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

section {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 250px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <section></section>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <section></section>
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: в таком случае приходиться каждую секцию заворачивать в контейнер. (<container><header></header></container>) (<container><footer></footer></container>) , нет ли более универсального решения?

Comment: @iKey это самый очевидный и простой вариант, остальное уже кажется костылями